# MarkLogic forest memory and cache memory, resulting in low memory warnings

Tags: warnings, low-memory, marklogic-10

we are seeing lot of low memory warnings in MarkLogic logs.

forest + cache is exceeding 100% of memory.

what exactly is forest memory why it is spiking up drastically during loading content. we are seeing spike in meters db from 4GB to 21-25GB during migration which is resulting in low memory warnings.

can any one shed some light on what exactly is forest memory?

some stats from our DB, we have 32GB RAM per host and we have 10 such nodes.
each host is having ondisk size of 19GB and in-memory-size of 3GB.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the actual issue.

the database in-memory settings are causing the issue. when the in-memory settings are high compared to default settings in marklogic 10, the forest memory usage is going high resulting in low memory warnings.

After using the default settings the low memory warnings are gone.

Still unable to understand how settings in MB is impacting the forest memory to go in GB's